# Python remove ... and spaces from a column

Tags: python, pandas, lambda

I have a dataset with a column having values:

```
.. >= 7 years
1 <= ... < 4 years
4 <= ... < 7 years
4 <= ... < 7 years
1 <= ... < 4 years
1 <= ... < 4 years
```

I am trying to remove the spaces & also the "..."

I have used the following codes:

```
data.columns = data.columns.map(lambda x: x.lstrip('...'))
```

This removes the .. from the first line but not for the other lines.
In order to remove the spaces I tried the following:

```
data.columns = data.columns.map(lambda x: x.strip())
```

But this doesn't seem to work.
Can someone help.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `str.strip` only removes space from the left and right ends of a string. To remove any space, use `str.replace` instead: `data.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace(' ', '')) `.

Comment: This doesn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pandas [`DataFrame.replace()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) accepts regex expressions, so you can remove the characters with:

```
df = df.replace(r"\s*\.*", "", regex = True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` to replace dots and spaces with empty string.
In your case use:

```
data.columns = data.columns.map(lambda x: x.replace('.', '').replace(' ', ''))
```